# AFNetworking 2.0 JSON parsing

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking-2

There were some changes in new version of AFNetworking (2.0).

I'm now confused with all new functions and I would like to know which class/method would be best for getting JSON data from http post request ? Should I build some singleton class like the one that was used in previous versions of AFNetworking ([AFNetworking (AFJSONRequestOperation) convert to AFHTTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411364/afnetworking-afjsonrequestoperation-convert-to-afhttpclient)) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am also wondering if I should use this same singleton class structure, anybody have an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are starting like this:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:AFNetworkingTestsBaseURLString:@"http://httpbin.org/"];
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST: ....
[operation start];
```

and you read the docs of [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/responseSerializer), you see that the manager already defaults to AFJSONRequestSerializer, AFCompoundResponseSerializer, so you don't have to do anything special.

Comment: Oh, I see, so that would be usual way ? Since I tried and there are plenty of classes which can achieve the same and I always get the json result right.

Comment: iOS 7 supports NSURLConnection and NSURLSession based networking, so you have a [couple of managers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VXHip.png) with two similar alternate flows, both using the serializers and multipart support.